# Exoplayer - How to prevent rebuffering when it's on Repeat mode?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using exoplayer 2, and have Repeat mode on, meaning it will keep playing the video once it reaches the end. However, after the video ends and plays again, it keeps rebuffering (reloading the video). How do I prevent this from happening?

```
player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build();
player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
```

**Edit1:**

Have tried using LoopingMediaSource, not sure if I am doing it correctly though?
Because it still rebuffers when it automatically replays the video.

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(mContext,
                Util.getUserAgent(mContext, "yourApplicationName"));
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mUrl);

        MediaSource videoSource =
                new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(uri);
        LoopingMediaSource loopingMediaSource = new LoopingMediaSource(videoSource);
        player.prepare(loopingMediaSource);
```

Comment: I believe that you need to implement caching.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to video buffering this is inevitable, as only a portion of the video is kept in memory.

What you can try is to adjust the buffering duration by setting a custom load control. Tune the **[setBufferDurationsMs](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl.Builder.html#setBufferDurationsMs-int-int-int-int-)** parameters to achieve your expected results.

```
 final DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(context);
 
 final DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl
            .Builder()
            .setBufferDurationsMs(25000, 50000, 1500, 2000)
            .build();

 player = new SimpleExoPlayer
            .Builder(context)
            .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
            .setLoadControl(loadControl)
            .build();
```

If by adjusting the parameters in setBufferDurationMs you can't still get the desired results, then you may need to implement the **drip-feeding technique** to improve rebuffering. Next a tutorial about how to implement such technique, targeted at ExoPlayer:

https://medium.com/@filipluch/how-to-improve-buffering-by-4-times-with-drip-feeding-technique-in-exoplayer-on-android-b59eb0c4d9cc

Comment: DefaultLoadControl doesnt have a build() method. Did you mean createDefaultLoadControl()?

Comment: Im using the latest one but I can't still find the method. https://i.imgur.com/QQkmdmb.png

Comment: Oh okay AS didn't display the yellow box over the dependency for some reason. But yeah after using build, it's still rebuffering :/

Comment: Did you tune the values in setBufferDurationsMs? The ones I placed are standard ones, you must adjust them according to what you may need, as rebuffering will always happen, the idea is to reduce buffering it to a minimum which makes it still usable and doesn't take too long.

Comment: Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/hB4NnanQ Im getting different videos everytime  I query an api so I can't adjust them everytime

Comment: Check the next link about the setBufferDurationsMs parameters, so you can adjust them properly while testing:  https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl.Builder.html#setBufferDurationsMs-int-int-int-int-

Comment: If you can't still achieve your results, I placed at the bottom of the answer a link for the drip-feeding technique, which can greatly improve rebuffering.

Comment: didnt get it to work, but ill look more into it tomorrow. Will give you the bounty

Answer (score 1):

You need cache data in `ExoPlayer`

- Create a custom cache data source factory

```
public class CacheDataSourceFactory implements DataSource.Factory {
    private final Context context;
    private final DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDatasourceFactory;
    private final long maxFileSize, maxCacheSize;

    public CacheDataSourceFactory(Context context, long maxCacheSize, long maxFileSize) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.maxCacheSize = maxCacheSize;
        this.maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
        String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        defaultDatasourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this.context,
                bandwidthMeter,
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, bandwidthMeter));
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor evictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(maxCacheSize);
        SimpleCache simpleCache = new SimpleCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "media"), evictor);
        return new CacheDataSource(simpleCache, defaultDatasourceFactory.createDataSource(),
                new FileDataSource(), new CacheDataSink(simpleCache, maxFileSize),
                CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE | CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR, null);
    }
}
```

- And the player

```
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    
    SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
    MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(url),
                new CacheDataSourceFactory(context, 100 * 1024 * 1024, 5 * 1024 * 1024), new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true); 
    exoPlayer.prepare(audioSource);
```

Comment: ```new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);``` doesn't accept bandwidthMeter as arguments  https://i.imgur.com/Up8c3Pu.png

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LoopingMediaSource`  and put it to player by:

```
player.prepare(loopingMediaSource)
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it's still looping and rebuffering again. Not sure if I am doing it correctly though. Code in edit above